# How to change value of @Html.EditorFor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on the simple webpage where user will be able to change some data.
I'm using `@Html.EditorFor` for changing that data. But I have some problems.

Here You can see my HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeviceUser, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeviceUser, new { @Value = ViewBag.id})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeviceUser)
    </div>
 </div>
```

As You can see I'm trying to replace `DeviceUser` with new Id which is passed from Controler using `ViewBag`.

But for unknow reason for me this textbox always holds old value.
Can anyone suggest me how to fix it?

Comment: You should change the value of property `DeviceUser` in your viewmodel, which is usually done in the controller. See this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing this

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeviceUser, new { @Value = ViewBag.id})`

to

`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DeviceUser, new { @Value = ViewBag.id})`